# Rails: Why isn't Guard waiting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, autotest

I am trying to use `Guard` instead of `Autotest` for `RSpec`, but I'm somewhat confused by its behavior.  When I run `bundle exec guard` it just launches a `pry` window.  I thought it is supposed to behave like Autotest where it just continues to run tests in the background every time there is a change.  What am I missing here?

When I launch `bundle exec guard`, this is what I get:

```
18:52:44 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
18:52:44 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
18:52:44 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/path/to/my/application'
[1] guard(main)>
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this.

Comment: Did you install guard-rspec?

Comment: Yeah - I'm just not exactly sure how to run it.

Comment: That's what you should get. Leave that window open in the background, and whenever you make changes and Guard runs your tests it will display the test output there.

Comment: But it's popping up an interactive shell - it doesn't seem like any process is running that I should be backgrounding.

Comment: have you watched the screencasts? See https://github.com/guard/guard#screencast

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated your Guardfile?  (./Guardfile in your app directory).  Mine looks like this:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Capybara features specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end
```

Your output listed above looks correct, Guard gives you an interactive shell as well as triggering things when files change.

Answer (score 0):

Running it with `-i` option should help

```
bundle exec guard -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Guard is running Pry for user interactions with it. Probably you haven't set to run RSpec guard at startup. To run it manually type `rspec` and hit return. It will run your Guard. To run all guards (if you have more than this one) just type `all` and hit return.

PS
Guard is still watching and will run your guard on file change, but it is showing Pry prompt to allow user interactions (described above).